# Exibir todos os elementos na tela

Tags: javascript

Estou com um problema no trecho de código abaixo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>02 - Promises Example</title>

<style type="text/css">
    
.promises {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: cursive;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


</body>

<script>
    var posts = fetch('https://willianjusten.com.br/search.json');
    // pending
    // resolved
    // rejected
    posts
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => data.reduce(post => {
            
            var teste = post.title;
            console.log(teste);
            const markup = `<div class="promises">${teste}</div>`;

        document.body.innerHTML = markup;
      
        }));



 
</script>
</html>
```

Eu preciso exibir todos os elementos na tela, porém ele só exibe o ultimo elemento do array.

Eu quero ter flexibilidade como exibir todo o conteúdo do json, ou todas as categorias, exemplo: todos os campos "date" ou todos os campos "title" e por ai vai, conseguem me dar um help?

Comment: `reduce` não server para iterar arrays da forma que você está utilizando, tente utilizar `data.forEach(post => {`, e então concatene o conteúdo com `document.body.innerHTML += markup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente é que como o André pontuou, usar a função `reduce` não te permitirá iterar por esse array da forma desejada. Usaremos `forEach`.

Outro ponto é que você está sobrescrevendo o body toda vez que um elemento pré-existente é adicionando perdendo tudo que tinha feito antes. Para resolver isso, usaremos as funções `createElement` e a função `appendChild` em conjunto.

```js
var valoresElement = document.getElementById('valores')

var posts = fetch('https://willianjusten.com.br/search.json');

posts
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(data => data.forEach(post => {
        var valorSingle = document.createElement('li')
        valorSingle.innerText = post.title
        valoresElement.appendChild(valorSingle)
    }))
```

```html
<ul id='valores'></ul>
```

Comment: Poha mano, valeu cara!

Answer (score 1):

Só para deixar registrado no site, se quiser fazer algo parecido com que estava fazendo pode criar uma tag **div** no Html e inserir os valores normalmente, apenas como já foi dito na resposta do João, não utilize **reduce**, mas, pode utilizar [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) ou [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) que o resultado será o mesmo:

```js
let posts = fetch('https://willianjusten.com.br/search.json');
// pending
// resolved
// rejected
posts
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(data => data.filter(post => {
    let teste = post.title;
    const markup = `<div class="promises">${teste}</div>`;
    let div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

    div.innerHTML += markup;

  }));
```

```css
.promises {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: cursive;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Sempre bom lembrar que existem outros métodos que nos permitem chegar a um resultado comum. Creio que sua colocação foi mais para deixar ciente de que eles existem Andrade, mas acho que é válido lembrar que as funções `map/filter` demandam mais tempo de execução do que a função `forEach`, justamente por terem sido pensadas para outras aplicações.

Comment: Exato João, criei o exemplo mais para deixar registrado mesmo que existem outros métodos, mas, o forEach é bem mais performático.